# Integrate $\int_0^y w^{a-1}(1-w)^{b-1}dw$

Tags: integration

I need help to solve this integral:
[image]

could someone please show me how to get the answer?
Thankyou.

Comment: This is [incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

Comment: The integral is incomplete Beta function, for $0 \le y \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of incomplete Beta function given by
$$
I=\int_0^y  w^{a-1} (1-w)^{b-1}dw=B(y;a,b),\quad \bigg(\Re(y^{-1}) \geq 1 \lor \Re(y^{-1}) \leq 0 \lor {y^{-1}} \not \in \mathbb{R}\bigg) \wedge \Re(a)>0
$$
where $y=(1-e^{(x\lambda)^c})$.  You can also define it as
$$
I=B(y;a,b)=y^a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1-b)_n}{n!(a+n)}y^n
$$
where $(1-b)_n$ is given by the Pochhammer symbol given by
$$
(1-b)_n\equiv \frac{\Gamma(1-b+n)}{\Gamma(1-b)}
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.